# Conway–Maxwell–Poisson (CMP) distribution and exponential family

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

So I have a question here about the CMP distribution:
[image]

My understanding is that $b(\theta)$ is only a function of $\theta$ but why is $v$ able to be included in that function, would $v$ not be a dispersion parameter instead; as that is the purpose of $v$.

I'm just having a hard time grasping the concept of exponential families as the parameterisation of $a(\phi), b(\theta)$ and $c(\phi, y)$ seem so arbitrary for me.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150209033550/http://www.stat.purdue.edu/%7Eovitek/STAT526-Spring11_files/pdfs/hw8-sol.pdf)

Comment: Your question is unclear: the notations $\theta$, $\phi$, $a(\cdot)$, $b(\cdot)$, $c(\cdot,\cdot)$ are not standard so please rephrase how you define an exponential family using such notations.

Comment: Before getting your reply, I must add that the answer sounds incorrect since the natural parameter should be $\theta=(\ln \lambda,\nu)$. Could you provide the reference from which you extracted this excerpt?

Comment: @Xi'an: Oh I see, I looked at the equation, where you can see that the natural parameters are what you wrote.  It's just that below in his "Therefore,…" he is not consistent

Comment: One conclusion you could reach, and correctly so, is that $\nu$ is not in fact a dispersion parameter in the exponential family sense!

Answer (score 0):

$a$ is your exponentiated carrier measure, and $b$ is your log-normalizer.  The log-normalizer is a function of the parameter vector, which is $\theta = [\lambda, \nu]$.  $\phi$ should to be the vector $y$.  $c$ makes no sense at all — remove it.

Comment: Could you please write down the expected shape of the exponential family so that we all agree on the definition of those terms?

Comment: @Xi'an what do you mean by shape?

Comment: @Xi'an: The density is
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\mbx}{\mathbf x}
\newcommand{\btheta}{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
f(\mbx \mid \btheta) &= \exp\bigl(\eta(\btheta) \cdot T(\mbx) - g(\btheta) + h(\mbx)\bigr)
\end{align} where $g$ is the log-normalizer, $h$ is the carrier measure, $\eta$ is the mapping to natural parameters and T is the mapping to sufficient statistics.

Comment: It would be easier for the OP if you'd use the original notations.

Comment: @Xi'an: As you pointed out in your comment, his notation doesn't make any sense.  It would be better for him to cite a reference and adapt to it.