# Does the following pmf belong to the exponential family?

Tags: self-study, distributions, exponential-family

I recently saw* a pmf:
$f(y)=\frac{\mu^y}{(y!)^\theta z(\mu,\theta)}$, where $z(\mu,\theta) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^i}{(i!)^\theta}$.

* It is a bonus question on a homework assignment.

My first impression is that it is somehow related to poisson distribution but I cannot figure out how.

Any ideas? Thanks.

To express it as an exponential family, following the approach of @Glen_b, I get that $\phi=\mu, T(y)=y, A(\phi)=log z(\mu,\theta)$, but is it right to include the additional parameter $\theta$ in $A(\phi)$? Am I missing anything?

Update:
I found another similar post which clarifies my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179561/conway-maxwell-poisson-cmp-distribution-and-exponential-family).

Comment: Where did you see this?  What is it used for (other than as a homework assignment, should it be one)?

Comment: This is so straightforward I doubt it can be anything but a class exercise or similar routine bookwork (possibly even an exam or test question - it's just the sort of thing I'd be tempted to ask, simple application of the principles without actually having been answered in class already). Please identify where this question comes from so that appropriate forms of help can be offered.. Where did you see the pmf? In a book? A paper? (in either of those cases, please offer a reference)

Comment: It is a bonus question on a homework assignment.

Comment: Thanks. please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question as appropriate - which is to say you should at least offer some indication of your own attempts (your first impression is correct - it does 'somehow relate' to the Poisson -  but is not directly relevant to answering the question). What does it take for something to be exponential family, for example (i.e. what's the definition you're working with)? What attempt have you may to see what parts correspond to the terms in the definition?

Comment: Re "*is it right to include the additional parameter*": Did you notice that my post made explicit reference to the parameter $\phi$ being a *vector*? You're asking a question I already answered! The product between $\eta$ and $T$ is a dot product, but I will edit to make it even clearer by writing the product of the two vectors in a more explicit manner

Answer (score 1):

Taking a definition of exponential family form for vector parameters (and avoiding the usual $\theta$ for the parameter vector):

$f_Y(y\mid\boldsymbol \phi) =  \exp\Big(\boldsymbol\eta({\boldsymbol \phi})^\top\, \mathbf{T}(y) - A({\boldsymbol \phi})+B(y) \Big)$

1. What would be in $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ for this set up?
2. Now consider $\log f:\:$ $\boldsymbol\eta({\boldsymbol \phi})^\top\, \mathbf{T}(y) - A({\boldsymbol \phi})+B(y)$

Taking logs of the f that you have in your question, can you identify any potential $A$, $\eta$, or $T$?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have modified my post above and identified some terms according to your form. However, is it correct for the "A" function to include two parameters? (My first post so I am still learning the format.)